# Failing to create and execute PL/SQL procedure from SQL*Plus

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

```
create or replace package XXX_MWA_LOV_TEST AS
    TYPE t_ref_csr IS REF CURSOR;
    PROCEDURE XXX_USERS_LOV (p_user_name IN VARCHAR2,x_users OUT NOCOPY t_ref_csr);
end XXX_MWA_LOV_TEST;
```

How to run `XXX_USERS_LOV` procedure in SQL*Plus?

I tried this code but getting the syntax error:

```
SQL> EXECUTE XXX_MWA_LOV_TEST.XXX_USERS_LOV('%',:my_p_out);
```

Procedure body:

```
create or replace package body XXX_MWA_LOV_TEST AS
  PROCEDURE XXX_USERS_LOV (x_users OUT NOCOPY t_ref_csr,p_user_name IN VARCHAR2) IS
  BEGIN
    OPEN x_users FOR select user_id,user_name,description 
      from fnd_user
      where user_name like p_user_name;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TESTING DATA');
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR IN USER LOV '|| SQLERRM);
  END XXX_USERS_LOV;

end XXX_MWA_LOV_TEST;
```

Comment: Do you have the procedure body defined?

Comment: i have updated procedure body.. kindly tel me how to execute procedure which contains ref cursor as a parameter.. Am new to this...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the order of the parameters must be the same in the spec and in the package body.

You can call the ref cursor like this:

```
 declare 
   v_cursor xxx_mwa_lov_test.t_ref_csr;
   var1 the_type_you_need;
   var2 the_type_you_need;
   ...
 begin
   xxx_mwa_lov_test.xxx_users_lov(v_cursor,'username...');

   loop
      fetch v_cursor into var1, var2...;
      exit when v_cursor%notfound;
      ... do what you want with the vars...
   end loop;
end;
/
```